# Install NuGet packages not shown in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

I open one of my old project to update the NuGet packages, but the installed list is empty. My other project do not have this problem.
    I check my settings and look correct. Any idea? See below attached screenshot:

[NuGet Installed list empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8qAZ.jpg)

[packages.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGDcr.jpg)

[Project Files List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ74X.jpg)

Thanks and have a nice day.

Update: I have add the screenshot of the project file list.

Update 2: For a start, I try to re-install the jQuery package, but got the following errors and ask me to restart visual studio.
 After restart, I try to re-install jQuery package, it give me the same error and ask me to restart again. The following are the error list and error in the output:

[TF400024](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uQBt.jpg)

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'jQuery.1.9.1' with respect to project 'MMS Attendance', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
>   Gathering dependency information took 1.1 sec
>   Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'jQuery.1.9.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
>   Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
>   Resolving actions to install package 'jQuery.1.9.1'
>   Resolved actions to install package 'jQuery.1.9.1'
>   Retrieving package 'jQuery 1.9.1' from 'nuget.org'.
>   Adding package 'jQuery.1.9.1' to folder 'D:\Work\Projects\MMS\Source\Website\Solution\packages'
>   Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Package 'jQuery.1.9.1' does not exist in project 'MMS Attendance'
>   Removing package 'jQuery.1.9.1' from folder 'D:\Work\Projects\MMS\Source\Website\Solution\packages'
>   TF400024: The change on D:\Work\Projects\MMS\Source\Website\Solution\packages\jQuery.1.9.1\Tools\uninstall.ps1 cannot be undone because a file already exists at D:\Work\Projects\MMS\Source\Website\Solution\packages\jQuery.1.9.1\Tools\uninstall.ps1. The file must be deleted from disk for the undo to succeed.
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlException: TF400024: The change on D:\Work\Projects\MMS\Source\Website\Solution\packages\jQuery.1.9.1\jQuery.1.9.1.nupkg cannot be undone because a file already exists at D:\Work\Projects\MMS\Source\Website\Solution\packages\jQuery.1.9.1\jQuery.1.9.1.nupkg. The file must be deleted from disk for the undo to succeed.
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.WebServiceLayerLocalWorkspaces.<>c__DisplayClass56_2.b__0(LocalWorkspaceProperties wp, WorkspaceVersionTable lv, LocalPendingChangesTable pc)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.LocalWorkspaceTransaction.Execute(AllTablesTransaction toExecute)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.WebServiceLayerLocalWorkspaces.UndoPendingChanges(String workspaceName, String ownerName, ItemSpec[] items, Failure[]& failures, String[] itemAttributeFilters, String[] itemPropertyFilters, Boolean& onlineOperation, Boolean deleteAdds, Int32& flags, Boolean checkForExistingItems)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Client.Undo(Workspace workspace, ItemSpec[] itemSpecs, Boolean updateDisk, Boolean deleteAdds, String[] itemAttributeFilters, String[] itemPropertyFilters, Int32 operationId)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.Undo(ItemSpec[] itemSpecs, Boolean updateDisk, Boolean deleteAdds, String[] itemAttributeFilters, String[] itemPropertyFilters)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.Undo(PendingChange[] pendingChanges)
>      at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.DefaultTFSSourceControlManager.PendDeleteFiles(IEnumerable`1 fullPaths, String root, INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext)
>      at NuGet.ProjectManagement.FileSystemUtility.DeleteFile(String fullPath, INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext)
>      at NuGet.ProjectManagement.FolderNuGetProject.d__24.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.d__86.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>      at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.d__74.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.d__73.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.d__11.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>      at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   Time Elapsed: 00:00:06.4465521
>   ========== Finished ==========

Comment: Where is your packages.config, under the solution folder or project folder? You can share us the screenshot for your Solution Explorer(Hide your personal information). If the packages.config under the solution folder, please convert it to project folder, because the NuGet team deprecated solution level packages in NuGet 3.0.https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/522

Comment: I have attached the project list screenshot of the solution explorer. The packages.config is in the project folder as you can see in the screenshot. I compare with my other project that don't have this issue, but I can't see the difference.

Comment: thanks for your update and reply. Not sure why you get this odd behavior, seems packages.config does not recognize by nuget. As a suggestion, you can try to delete this packages.conig file(Back up it), then reinstall those packages via nuget. Check if it works fine.

Comment: I try to reinstall the package, but failed to install. I edit the above to include the errors occur when I install the jquery package. The errors contain the "TeamFoundation", so I just wonder does it have anything to do with it? I use the Team services for version control.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Have you include the packages in to the version control? If yes, please exclude the packages by .tfignore file. And if not help you, please create a new project(not add it in the version control), copy the scripts to the new project, add the packages to the project, check if it works fine.

Comment: Just an update: I notice my project loaded in my notebook without this issue. The VS2017 version in my notebook is 15.3.5 and the VS2017 in my PC is 15.5.0. From what I understand, there is no rolled back, so I uninstall the VS2017 15.5.0 and since cannot find the version 15.3.5, I installed the VS2017 15.4.5. Now the NuGet seem to be working normally, so it's seem that VS2017 15.5.0 update break something.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could convert your comment to an answer and mark it after time limit, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.